# Calculating the Covariant Derivatives on Latitudes of a Sphere

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, surfaces

I am currently trying to solve a question, but am $\textit{really}$ struggling with the idea of Covariant Derivative, and would love for someone to help me out. The question reads:

> On a sphere of Radius $R$, parametrized by:
>   $$\sigma(\theta, \phi) = (R\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta), R\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta), R\cos(\theta))$$
>   Consider the curves $\theta=c\in\mathbb{R}$.
>   Parametrize the Curves by arc-length $s$. Then, consider the southward pointing Vector Field $X_{\theta}$. Compute the Covariant Derivative:
>   $$\frac{D }{\partial s}(X_{\theta})$$
>   Further, what is the Covariant Derivative $$\frac{D}{\partial s}(\sin(s)\cdot X_{\theta})$$

Now, I have calculated the curves by arc-length. However, I am confused by how to compute the Covariant Derivative. In $\textit{Do Carmo's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces}$, the definition of the Covariant Derivative is given by:
\begin{align*}
\frac{DW}{\partial t} &= (a'+\Gamma_{11}^1au'+\Gamma_{12}^1av'+\Gamma_{12}^1 bu'+\Gamma_{22}^1 bv')x_u+(b'+\Gamma_{11}^2au'+\Gamma_{12}^2av'+\Gamma_{12}^2bu'+\Gamma_{22}^2bv')x_v
\end{align*}
Where the surface is parametrized as $x(u(t),v(t))$ and $w(t)$ is given by:
$$w(t)=a(t)x_u+b(t)x_v$$
Now, in my case, $X_{\theta}$ is (I'm assuming) just the partial derivative w.r.t $\theta$ of my parametrization? But how do I compute $a(t)$ and $b(t)$? Is there an easier way to solve this question? I know of the way of finding the Christoffel Symbols and finding $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ through ODE's, but am I missing something?

Comment: I think I've mentioned this to you before, but you might find [my differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) a useful reference to supplement doCarmo with more concrete examples. In particular, I have this problem completely worked out in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to try and solve this, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. So, since $X_{\theta}=\sigma_{\theta}$, we require that if we write:
$$X_{\theta}=a(s)\cdot \sigma_{\theta}+b(s)\cdot\sigma_{\phi}$$
Then $a(s)=1$ and $b(s)=0$. Plugging this into the equation in the question:

$$\frac{D}{\partial s}(X_{\theta}) = (\Gamma_{11}^1\theta'+\Gamma_{12}^1\phi')\cdot\sigma_{\theta}+(\Gamma_{11}^2\theta'+\Gamma_{12}^2\phi')\cdot\sigma_{\phi}$$
Where the Prime denotes $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$. Now, having found that:
$$\theta'=0, \>\>\phi' = \frac{1}{\rho\sin(c)}$$
Also, noting that:
$$\Gamma_{11}^1=0, \>\>\Gamma_{12}^2=0, \>\>\Gamma_{11}^2 = 0, \>\>\Gamma_{12}^2 = \cot(\theta)=\cot(c)$$Plugging these values in above yields:
$$\frac{D}{\partial s}(X_{\theta}) = \frac{\cot(c)}{\rho\sin(c)}\cdot\sigma_{\phi}$$